# Finding maximum in the boundary limits using mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

Im trying to find the maximum of the function on the boundary:

```
f[x_, y_] := 10 Log[x^2 + 2 y^2 + 1] - x^2 - y^2
```

That is within the boundary:

```
x^2 + y^2 ≤ 16
```

What I've tried to do is analyse:

The derivative of `f[4 Cos(t), 4 Sin(t)]`, to find the maximum in the boundary.

```
g[t_] := f[4*Cos[t], 4*Sin[t]]
Solve[D[g[t], t] == 0]
```

However, Mathematica gives me something like:

> `g'[t] -> 0`

Also, `Maximize` and `NMaximize` do not work for this problem. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Is `Maximize[f[x, y],{x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 16, {x, y}]]` or `Maximize[{f[x, y], x^2 + y^2 <= 16},{x, y}]`what you are looking for?  See [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) documentation.

Comment: Something went amiss with the definitions. `Solve` works just fine here (I added a range to avoid conditional results with integer-valued parameters). `In[502]:= f[x_, y_] := 10*Log[x^2 + 2*y^2 + 1] - x^2 - y^2
g[t_] := f[4*Cos[t], 4*Sin[t]]
Solve[D[g[t], t] == 0 && 0 <= t < 2*Pi]

Out[504]= {{t -> 0}, {t -> \[Pi]/2}, {t -> \[Pi]}, {t -> (3 \[Pi])/2}}`

Answer (score 2):

Just as in the comments suggested:

```
Maximize[{f[x, y], x^2 + y^2 <= 16}, {x, y}]
```

> {-(19/2) + 10 Log[20], {x -> 0, y -> -Sqrt[(19/2)]}}

or on the Boundary

```
 Maximize[{f[x, y], x^2 + y^2 == 16}, {x, y}]
```

> {-16 + 10 Log[33], {x -> 0, y -> -4}}

Comment: From the symmetry, the maximum also occur at the positive values of y

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with derivatives, or if you have lower versions of Mathematica, where Maximize can't solve this analytically:

First derivatives have to be zero, second one less than zero, together with region condition

```
{dsol = Solve[
    D[f[x, y], x] == 0 && D[f[x, y], y] == 0 && 
    D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] < 0 && D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] < 0 && 
    x^2 + y^2 <= 16, {x, y}], 
    dsol // N, 
    max = f[x, y] /. dsol, 
    max // N}

(*   {{{x -> 0, y -> -Sqrt[(19/2)]}, {x -> 0, y -> Sqrt[19/2]}}, 
      {{x -> 0.,y -> -3.08221}, {x -> 0., y -> 3.08221}}, 
      {-(19/2) + 10 Log[20], -(19/2) + 10 Log[20]}, 
      {20.4573, 20.4573}}   *)
```

But it doesn't work, if there are no extrema within boundary.